# SignalR ASP.NET MVC 4 Windows 8 Visual Studio 2012 JS Hubs Cannot be Found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, signalr

I running this super simple SignalR test app that I wrote in VS 2012 / MVC 4 / Win8.

When I run I get the following error everytime. For some reason it looks like it cannot load `/signalr/hubs` JS.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? You can grab the solution from here.

http://andrewherrick.com/spike/SignalR_AJ_Hi.zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things

1. `RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();` is included after `RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);`. It should be included before any other routes. [SignalR FAQ](https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq).
2. Your project is not compiling the `Global.asax.cs` (at least the version I downloaded). You can test this by inserting some invalid code in the file Global.asax.cs and the project would still compile. Exclude it it from the project. Do a clean and full rebuild. Include it back and then do a full rebuild. Make sure that you *do* get the compilation errors for the invalid code (so that you know that it is being compiled). Remove the invalid code and recompile.

Answer (score 1):

In your app start do:

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
```

See the **Why does signalr/hubs return 404 or Why do I get 'myhub' is undefined?** section in: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Faq